# I need to get equity and position price at the same moment in MT5 Python

Tags: python-3.x, mql5, metatrader5

Im trying to get equity and price of positions at the same moment. With that i mean, i need the exact price that used when MT5 terminal calculate equity of account.

I'm using python and MT5 module to do so. I have tried multiprocessing and that cause MT5 Terminal to stop answering. I have tried threading which is seems works but results aren't correct or as i expected. When i have take screen shoot from terminal i calculate different results. Probably process to get equity and positions price are different processes inside and price changing until those different loadouts complete.

I need a advice or advices about what to try next. I heard about you can get data with MT Web Terminal instead MT5 but i didn't find any documantation about it.